# How to find the length of a prolog database

Tags: database, prolog

I wanted to know a way to count the length of a database in PROLOG.
I found this predicate :

```
length([ ], 0).
length([H|T],N) :- length(T,M), N  is  M+1.
```

But it only works works with a list. 
So if you have an idea how to do it, let me know

Comment: "The length of a database" seems like a meaningless quantity, like the weight of a megabyte or the volume of an idea. Your predicate operates on lists; it is measuring the length of a list. You will have to rephrase the question to make it meaningful, and it may help to include a query with the result you expect.

Comment: Do you really mean counting how many facts of a given functor name are asserted? `findall(_, <call_your_fact_with_dummy_arguments>, L), length(L, Size).`